# Transferring to a new PhD program. How to explain lack of ability to find funding in application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, transfer-student

I have completed 1.5 years of a PhD program and I am told now that there is no funding left for me to continue. I am looking for new departments to apply to. How should I explain this situation in my resume and interviews? Should I be upfront and simply state that there is no money left or should I frame it more like it is my decision to leave because I think the research at the new place is amazing or something?

Comment: Without additional information, my nasty brain would translate "no money left" to "no money left for that guy".

Comment: that is precisely what happened!

Comment: Really difficult situation, there is no easy way out, and details can only be explained in an interview. The problem is that in a CV there is no way to explain this.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much information you anticipate coming out in your recommendation letters.

Comment: @anon_945500 i'm not sure you understand the implication of Karl's comment. He's saying that some people would believe that your advisor/department no longer want to fund you in particular. Otherwise, they would try harder to find further funding or switch you to a different project with funding.